# Extracting and evaluating words in a text string against another dataset

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two sets of data that I will be evaluating against one another. A heavily reduced example looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(sqldf)
library(dbplyr)
library(httr)
library(purrr)
library(jsonlite)
library(magrittr)
library(tidyr)
library(tidytext)

    people_records_ex <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 456L, 789L), name = c("Anna Wilson", 
                                                                           "Jeff Smith", "Craig Mills"), biography = c("Student at Ohio State University. Class of 2024.", 
                                                                                                                       "Second year law student at Stanford. Undergrad at William & Mary", 
                                                                                                                       "University of North Texas Volleyball!")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                      -3L))
    
    
    college_records_ex <- structure(list(college_id = c(234L, 567L, 891L, 345L), college_name = c("Ohio State University", 
                                                                                                  "Stanford", "William & Mary", "University of North Texas"), college_city = c("Columbus", 
                                                                                                                                                                               "Stanford", "Williamsburg", "Denton"), college_state = c("OH", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        "CA", "VA", "TX")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        ))
```

I am trying to create a match against the contents of the `biography` text string in `people_records_ex` against `college_name` in `college_records_ex` so the final output will look like this:

```
    final_records_ex <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 456L, 456L, 789L), name = c("Anna Wilson", 
                                                                                "Jeff Smith", "Jeff Smith", "Craig Mills"), college_name = c("Ohio State University", 
                                                                                                                                             "Stanford", "William & Mary", "University of North Texas"), college_city = c("Columbus", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                          "Stanford", "Williamsburg", "Denton"), college_state = c("OH", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   "CA", "VA", "TX")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   ))
```

Or to provide a more visual example of the final output I'm expecting:

[image]

But when I run the following code, it produces zero results, which is not correct:

```
college_extract <- people_records_ex %>%
  left_join(college_records_ex, by = c("biography" = "college_name")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(college_state)) %>% dplyr::select(id, name, college_name, college_city, college_state) %>% distinct()
```

What am I doing incorrectly and what would the correct version look like?

Comment: Considering there's no real pattern in number of words, words before college name or anything AND you can have more than one college per student, I'd say there's no easy way to solve your issue

Comment: That's fine! So what would be the best way to try and solve it? What would that look like?

Comment: are universities in biographies always correctly spelled? If so, i'd turn everything into lowercase and create check every university against each biography using `str_detect`, mark with 1 when there's a match, then you can extract which university matches each student has

Comment: Let's assume most are? I can't guarantee they will be perfect spelling, so it would be nice to capture some of those, but if that makes your answer way more difficult, not a huge deal.

Comment: So what would that look like in the context of my code?

Comment: Sorry, edited my latest answer with a fast guess of what I'd do. Might get quite slow if you database is too big, though

Comment: I don't see an answer below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a very tidy and straightforward solution with `fuzzy_join`:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
fuzzy_join(
  people_records_ex, college_records_ex,
  by  = c("biography" = "college_name"),
  match_fun = str_detect,
  mode = "left"
) %>%
select(-biography)
   id        name college_id              college_name college_city college_state
1 123 Anna Wilson        234     Ohio State University     Columbus            OH
2 456  Jeff Smith        567                  Stanford     Stanford            CA
3 456  Jeff Smith        891            William & Mary Williamsburg            VA
4 789 Craig Mills        345 University of North Texas       Denton            TX
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the college names in the biographies are spelled out exactly as they appear in the colleges table and the datasets are relatively small, all matches can be generated with a regex of all college names as follows

```r
library(dplyr)

people_records_ex <- structure(list(id = c(123L, 456L, 789L), name = c(
  "Anna Wilson",
  "Jeff Smith", "Craig Mills"
), biography = c(
  "Student at Ohio State University. Class of 2024.",
  "Second year law student at Stanford. Undergrad at William & Mary",
  "University of North Texas Volleyball!"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -3L
)) %>% tibble::tibble()


college_records_ex <- structure(list(college_id = c(234L, 567L, 891L, 345L), college_name = c(
  "Ohio State University",
  "Stanford", "William & Mary", "University of North Texas"
), college_city = c(
  "Columbus",
  "Stanford", "Williamsburg", "Denton"
), college_state = c(
  "OH",
  "CA", "VA", "TX"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L)) %>%
  tibble::tibble()
```

```r
# join college names in a regex pattern
colleges_regex <- paste0(college_records_ex$college_name, collapse = "|")

colleges_regex
#> [1] "Ohio State University|Stanford|William & Mary|University of North Texas"

# match all against bio, giving a list-column of matches
people_records_ex %>%
  mutate(matches = stringr::str_match_all(biography, colleges_regex))
#> # A tibble: 3 × 4
#>      id name        biography                                           matches 
#>   <int> <chr>       <chr>                                               <list>  
#> 1   123 Anna Wilson Student at Ohio State University. Class of 2024.    <chr[…]>
#> 2   456 Jeff Smith  Second year law student at Stanford. Undergrad at … <chr[…]>
#> 3   789 Craig Mills University of North Texas Volleyball!               <chr[…]>

# unnest the list column wider to give 1 row per person per match
people_records_ex %>%
  mutate(matches = stringr::str_match_all(biography, colleges_regex)) %>%
  tidyr::unnest_longer(matches)
#> # A tibble: 4 × 4
#>      id name        biography                                            match…¹
#>   <int> <chr>       <chr>                                                <chr>  
#> 1   123 Anna Wilson Student at Ohio State University. Class of 2024.     Ohio S…
#> 2   456 Jeff Smith  Second year law student at Stanford. Undergrad at W… Stanfo…
#> 3   456 Jeff Smith  Second year law student at Stanford. Undergrad at W… Willia…
#> 4   789 Craig Mills University of North Texas Volleyball!                Univer…
#> # … with abbreviated variable name ¹​matches[,1]
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-26 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

This may be joined back to the college table such that it is annotated with college info.

Comment: This is a good answer as well. Thank you, playboy!

Answer (score 1):

In base R you can do:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(college_records_ex$college_name, 
                      \(x) people_records_ex[grep(x, people_records_ex$biography),1:2])) |> 
  cbind(college_records_ex[-1])
```

This does some matching and I subsetted the first two columns which are the id and name, cbinding it with the second data.frame getting rid of the first column

```
    id        name              college_name college_city college_state
1  123 Anna Wilson     Ohio State University     Columbus            OH
2  456  Jeff Smith                  Stanford     Stanford            CA
21 456  Jeff Smith            William & Mary Williamsburg            VA
3  789 Craig Mills University of North Texas       Denton            TX
```

Comment: This is a good answer as well. Thank you, playboy!